# DataGrid.ScrollIntoView() does not work, using DataGridTemplateColumn and MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, scroll, selecteditem

UserControl `DataGrid` XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="NamingConventionDataGrid" Width="{Binding ElementName=toolbar, Path=ActualWidth}" MinHeight="100"
     HorizontalAlignment="Left" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
     VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="auto" 
     CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
     CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" Background="White" BorderThickness="1"
     VerticalGridLinesBrush="{StaticResource RowGrayBrush}" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{StaticResource RowGrayBrush}"
     RowBackground="White" AlternatingRowBackground="{StaticResource RowGrayBrush}" AlternationCount="2"
     ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}"
     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
     AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow"
     RowHeaderWidth="15" RowHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowHeaderStyle}" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding ReferenceValues, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
     MaxHeight="230" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
```

ViewModel Code:

```
 ReferenceValues = tempRefs;

 SelectedName = ReferenceValues.FirstOrDefault();
 _view.NamingConventionDataGrid.SelectedItem = SelectedName;
 _view.NamingConventionDataGrid.UpdateLayout();
 _view.NamingConventionDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(SelectedName);
```

When I call the `ScrollIntoView()` with the `SelectedItem` object {Binding}, it selects the object (I know this because other things on the WPF application change), but it doesn't scroll to where the object is, and the `SelectedItem` object isn't highlighted like when you click on the `DataGrid`. Am I missing some code sonewhere that will let me do scroll to where the `SelectedItem` is and also highlight it as if a user had scrolled to the item and clicked on the row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgot to set a `Binding` from `_view` object to map to the `UserControl`.

Once I had added the below code, everything worked again.

```
 model._view = _view.NamingConventionControl;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is due to the DataGrid only creating containers for those items visible and a few in each direction.

Try setting the IsVirtualizing property of your DataGrid like so:

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
```

I was having similar issues with supporting multiple selection and scrolling until I did this.

Comment: Vote-up for usefulness, but it wasn't the source of my problem. :)